# Android Studio closes automatically after short time

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio closes automatically after ~1 minute. I'm using AS 1.4 and it was wokring some days ago.

I have changed value of `-XX:MaxPermSize=350m` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` in `studio.exe.vmoptions` and `studio64.exe.vmoptions` files, but has not solved the problem.

I re-installed AS and re-installed Window but the same problem is still exist.

Comment: Re-installed windows? :O

Comment: How is DSpace related to this?

Comment: Does the problem occur even if you don't change those values?

Comment: @Madhukar Hebbar - Yes, i have no way. Just tried. :(

Comment: @Tim Castelijns - I'm not sure, it's the first time i have asked a question on this site. :d

Comment: Do you have any ideas guys?

Comment: Do you have an answer to my 2nd comment?

Comment: Please update your android studio if possible or Download latest build from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html . Report studio bug here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar 1.4 is the latest. It was released like a week ago

Comment: @TimCastelijns I agree. :)

Comment: I'm using the latest version. I lost ~ 2 days for this.

Comment: Up to yesterday it has just not worked. I increased heap size, increased free space in folder where i put sdk folder. I don't know what should i do now, i can not work if the problem is still exist. :( :(

Comment: This is impossible to solve this without any logs. There could be problems with android-studio, JVM and even your OS.

Comment: @LeChiffre - Yes, it closes without message. I have re-installed OS but has not solved the problem.

Comment: Facing same issue, didn't find any solution????

Comment: @Blundell No bro, I did not use VM.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Android SDK manager separately and be sure that everything is up to date. I have just had the same problem (yesterday I was updating) but after installing the latest *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)* my Android Studio is not closing anymore.

I'm not sure if thats the reason but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks! I would try not to post with an empty stomach

Comment: @juanmeanwhile - Oh, everything is up to date? I should try this, btw my sdk folder is ~50 GB.